# Getting rid of Drupal User Menu for responsiveness purposes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drupal-7

I am working on this Drupal site for a friend of mine: http://todatoda.com

I am using the Bootstrap theme in order to achieve maximum responsiveness and I am getting there. Problem is the secondary menu (User Menu) is always showing as a button on small screens, eventhough it has been completely disabled on the configuration and its links are also disabled on admin>structure>menus.

On big screens (desktop and tablets) all works fine. On smartphones, however, this is what I see:

[image: notice the button]
<sub>(source: [brodtec.com](http://brodtec.com/stack.png))</sub>

The button, of course, does nothing when clicked. So it just stays there to annoy me.

I even tried to set display:none for all css related to this funky button, without success:

```
/* Disable funky navbar button - still not working * /
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
border-color: #ddd;
display: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
background-color: #ddd;
display: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
color: #777;
display: none;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
display: none;
}
.navbar-toggle {
position: relative;
float: right;
padding: 9px 10px;
margin-top: 8px;
margin-right: 15px;
margin-bottom: 8px;
background-color: transparent;
border: 1px solid transparent;
border-radius: 4px;
display: none;
}
input, button, select, textarea {
font-family: inherit;
font-size: inherit;
line-height: inherit;
display: none;
}
button, html input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] {
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-appearance: button;
display: none;
}
button, input {
line-height: normal;
display: none;
}
icon-bar {
display: none;
}
element.style {
display: none;
}
```

All help is welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the button using only CSS, you can do it:

```
header .navbar-toggle {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Or simply:

```
.navbar-toggle {
  display: none !important;
}
```

To delete all toggle menus.
I don't use bootstrap, but the best option is to delete the menu via edit page.tpl.php or the theme configuration.

Regards.

Comment: I have tried a similar aproach, Mario, as you can see in the css snippet I have posted along with the original message. Still, I tried exactly what you suggested. No success. Just in case, let me tell you and other possible readers I am doing a drush cc all after every css modification. My goal is not to change the templates. However, if this seems to be the only solution, I will do this! Thanks! :-)

Comment: Did you add !important to the css rule?

Comment: Yep! And I know my css file is being read once other styles have been properly applied. After your suggestion, I edited the portion I included in the original message (and also your suggestions) to include !important to all of the display: none rules. I am pretty sure I am making a very stupid mistake and I just cannot see it. Again, thanks for helping me with this!

Comment: I do not use bootstrap, but check the page.tpl.php and remove the user menu render. Or go to the theme options and disable this menu. Maybe there is a block with the menu and it's rendered here.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use page.tpl.php as I could not find a way to acomplish what I wanted just by tweaking the css file. So, here are the steps:

1. Copy the page.tpl.php file into your own theme folder. In my case, it ended up at /var/www/sites/todatoda/theme/system/page.tpl.php
2. Find this portion of code and comment ad the invisible div:

   ```
     <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
     <div style = "visibility:hidden">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```
3. Just in case, also comment the place where the secondary menu gets rendered:

   ```
        <?php if (!empty($secondary_nav)): ?>
   ```

   -->
4. Save the file and clear the caches (drush cc all)

Done!

Comment: I also use Bootstrap theme but I do need that user menu. However, good to know that little trick just in case!!! Thanks :-)